# Как добавить id к созданному тегу?

Tags: javascript

На странице есть фиксированный блок, при скролле блок автоматически оборачивается в тег aside через `document.createElement`, как к данному тегу добавить id `#aside-fixed`?

```js
(function() {
  var a = document.querySelector('#aside-fixed'),
    b = null,
    P = 200;
  window.addEventListener('scroll', Ascroll, false);
  document.body.addEventListener('scroll', Ascroll, false);

  function Ascroll() {
    if (b == null) {
      var Sa = getComputedStyle(a, ''),
        s = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < Sa.length; i++) {
        if (Sa[i].indexOf('overflow') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('padding') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('border') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('outline') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('box-shadow') == 0 || Sa[i].indexOf('background') == 0) {
          s += Sa[i] + ': ' + Sa.getPropertyValue(Sa[i]) + '; '
        }
      }
      b = document.createElement('aside');
      b.style.cssText = s + ' box-sizing: border-box; width: ' + a.offsetWidth + 'px;';
      a.insertBefore(b, a.firstChild);
      var l = a.childNodes.length;
      for (var i = 1; i < l; i++) {
        b.appendChild(a.childNodes[1]);
      }
      a.style.height = b.getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
      a.style.padding = '0';
      a.style.border = '0';
    }
    var Ra = a.getBoundingClientRect(),
      R = Math.round(Ra.top + b.getBoundingClientRect().height - document.querySelector('#article').getBoundingClientRect().bottom); // селектор блока, при достижении нижнего края которого нужно открепить прилипающий элемент
    if ((Ra.top - P) <= 0) {
      if ((Ra.top - P) <= R) {
        b.className = 'stop';
        b.style.top = -R + 'px';
      } else {
        b.className = 'sticky';
        b.style.top = P + 'px';
      }
    } else {
      b.className = '';
      b.style.top = '';
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
      a.children[0].style.width = getComputedStyle(a, '').width
    }, false);
  }
})()
```

Comment: `b.id = "aside-fixed"`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте функцией setAttribute